# Quarkus native container-build

Tags: maven, quarkus, graalvm

I have write a small quarkus application and I create a native executable with the command:

```
mvn package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

The process works fine (I'm able to deploy the app inside a docker container and everything works fine), but I don't understand what the packaging process (with the param -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true) does behind the scene (for example, I haven't GraalVm on my pc; how can the process create a native image? Does the process "start" a container with graal, package the java inside the container and then return the artifact?).

 Searching online I find only tutorials to create native images for containers that don't explain how the process works. 
 Thanks for any explanation or suggestion on where to find useful information.

Answer (score 0):

## Classic way

As stated in [Quarkus Documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image), you'll need to install and configure GraalVM in order to be able to compile to native.

> Mandrel or GraalVM installed and configured appropriately

You'll also need a working C environment

> **What does having a working C developer environment mean?**
>
> On Linux, you will need GCC, and the glibc and zlib headers.
>
> ...
>
> On macOS, XCode provides the required dependencies
>
> ...
>
> On Windows, you will need to install the Visual Studio 2017 Visual C++ Build Tools

## Without GraalVM on your machine (but Linux only)

You could also tell quarkus that you don't have GraalVM (and don't want to bother installing it). Quarkus will use your container runtime to get what it needs to do its task.
Simply add this param :

```bash
-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

> If this build should be done using a container runtime. Unless container-runtime is also set, docker will be used by default. If docker is not available or is an alias to podman, podman will be used instead as the default.

See [reference](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus-core-quarkus-core) for more info

Comment: This exaclty the documentation that I read: the problem is that doesn't explain the details of what happen when I compile with the parameter -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true;